# Isn't JOIN's ON clause predicate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

For the below query to find customer growth YOY based on product orders.

```
SELECT 
    Cur.orderyear,
    Cur.numcusts AS curnumcusts, 
    Prv.numcusts AS prvnumcusts,
    Cur.numcusts - Prv.numcusts AS growth
FROM (
      SELECT 
        YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear,
        COUNT(DISTINCT custid) AS numcusts
      FROM Sales.Orders
      GROUP BY YEAR(orderdate)) AS Cur
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT 
            YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear,
            COUNT(DISTINCT custid) AS numcusts
         FROM Sales.Orders
         GROUP BY YEAR(orderdate)) AS Prv
ON Cur.orderyear = Prv.orderyear + 1
```

Produces below output

| orderyear | curnumcusts | prvnumcusts | growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 67 | NULL | NULL |
| 2021 | 86 | 67 | 19 |
| 2022 | 81 | 86 | -5 |

My query is how does `ON Cur.orderyear = Prv.orderyear + 1` work?

If `Cur.orderyear` is 2021 then `Prv.orderyear + 1` would be 2022. So, 2021 = 2022? How is it possible for records to match between two different table expressions (albeit same/duplicate expression).

I was under the assumption that `ON` was a predicate to find data equality between two joined tables rather than matching with data (not sure if what I just said make any sense).

Could you please help me understand what exactly `ON` does here?

Comment: If `cur.orderyear` is 2021 then `prv.orderyear` has to be 2020 for the equation to work - basic maths, 2020 + 1 = 2021. Which is I assume exactly what you want, to show lasts year's results with this year's.

Comment: You can put whatever boolean expressions you want in the ON clause. E.g. `ON c1 < c2 and c3 not in (cx, cy) or c4 like upper(substring...`. if evaluated to TRUE, return data!

Comment: Side note: this query is done much better using window functions eg `LAG`

Comment: @DaleK Table expression in FROM and LEFT JOIN (i.e cur & prv) both have same expression and result set. So, logically speaking (cur.orderyear <> prv.orderyear + 1) i.e. 2021 <> 2022.

Comment: @Charlieface yeah window functions are the best candidate but I just wanted to understand logic in the ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh sure but how is cur.orderyear = prv.orderyear + 1 (i.e. 2021 = 2022)? since alias cur & prv both have the same expression and result set.

Comment: Both have the same expression, but one is this year and one is last year. The inner queries cover all years, the means last year is joined to this year

Comment: Add  `prv.orderyear` and `prv.orderyear + 1` to the SELECT list, and you'll understand.

Comment: @jarlh thanks a lot, it finally clicked. Its due to carestian combination before applying "ON". I get it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `Cur` and `Prev` are both queried from the same `Sales.Orders` is inconsequential.

You can think of it like this:

- The inner query for `Cur` is executed. The details of what it queries aren't important - the only thing that's important is that a dataset is returned. We call this dataset `Cur`.
- Similarly, the inner query for `Prev` is executed. Here too, the only thing that's important is that a dataset is returned, and we call it `Prev`.
- Now, having two datasets, each one with its own, independent, `orderyear` column, we can join them according to the condition `Cur.orderyear = Prv.orderyear + 1`.

Comment: I agree if cur.orderyear and (prv.orderyear + 1) both had same value but in this case its different. I don't know what I am miss here :( How could join match/combine when condition fails?

Comment: It doesn't match when the condition fails, for every row in the FROM sub-query, one and only one row from the LEFT JOIN sub-query is joined in, the row for the previous yea which is the only row which matches the ON condition.

Comment: @DaleK, yup, that's what the condition `Cur.orderyear = Prv.orderyear + 1` does - the year is made distinct in the subqueries thanks to their `group by` clauses.

Comment: Yes I know,, I'm trying to explain to OP